# Displaying a map in EPSG:26915 projection in OpenLayers 3

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

My GIS experience is limited to having worked on several Geospatial Humanities projects. That is to say that I still struggle significantly with the technology (and terminology) in getting to my goal. I am working on moving a project from OpenLayers2 to OpenLayers3. I have a historical map served as a WMS from an Iowa State ArcServer that is in EPSG:26915 projection. The following code is what I use to successfully display the map in OpenLayers2:

```
var map;
function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{
        projection:'EPSG:26915',
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(202159,4470000,737457.523439407,4822691.7712555),
        fractionalZoom: true
    });
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        'OpenLayers WMS',
        'http://ags.gis.iastate.edu/arcgisserver/services/Ortho/andreas/ImageServer/WMSServer',
        {layers: 'basic'},
        {isBaseLayer: true },
        {}
    );
    map.addLayer(wms);
    if (!map.getCenter()){
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }
}
```

I have a number of unsuccessful attempts to display this using OpenLayers3, trying to piece together what I need from the ol3 examples and documentation. Here is my most recent unsuccessful attempt:

```
var map;    
function init() {
    var andreas_url = 'http://ags.gis.iastate.edu/arcgisserver/services/Ortho/andreas/ImageServer/WMSServer';
    var andreas_extent = [202073.808723, 4470598.397186, 736849.210393, 4822673.786539]
    var andreas_projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'EPSG:26915',
          // The extent is used to determine zoom level 0. Recommended values for a
          // projection's validity extent can be found at http://epsg.io/.
        extent: andreas_extent,
        units: 'm'
    });
    ol.proj.addProjection(andreas_projection);
    var andreas_view = new ol.View ({
        projection: andreas_projection,
        center: [469163,4653689],
        zoom:1      
    });
    map = new ol.Map({
        target:'map_container',
        renderer:'canvas',
        view: andreas_view
    })      
    var andreas_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: andreas_url,
            params:{
                'LAYERS':'basic', 
                'TILED':true
            }
        })
    });
    map.addLayer(andreas_layer);
}
```

The WMS Capabilities URL for this map is here:

http://ags.gis.iastate.edu/arcgisserver/services/Ortho/andreas/ImageServer/WMSServer?Request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&

Can anybody see what I might be doing wrong, or does anybody have a good resource for learning about projections in OL3?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an  `ol.source.ImageWMS` inside a `ol.layer.Tile` you must use an `ol.source.TileWMS` instead.

Here is 2 example which can help you :

[Single Image WMS example with custom projection](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/wms-image-custom-proj.html)

[Tile Image WMS example with custom projection](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/wms-custom-proj.html)